# How to filter rows if values in col2 dose not exist in col1

Tags: sql, loops, apache-spark

I am using spark SQL and python to perform this.
I have Data like this:

```
|  date  | col1| col2 | 

|01011245|  ABE|   ATL|
|01020600|  ABE|   DTW|
|01021245|  DTW|   ATL|
|01020605|  ABE|   ATL|
```

I want to filter the data such that we will show only rows containing values in col2 that exist somewhere in col1 (not necessary in the same row).

for example, in our small example it should be:

```
|  date  | col1| col2 | 

|01020600|  ABE|   DTW|
```

I think maybe a for loop with a condition on each row value should work, But I didn't succeed with it.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM yourTable AS t WHERE t.col2 IN ( SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM yourTable )`

Comment: @Dai Please add an Answer if you have a unique solution.

Comment: @DANY A well-structured S.O. question includes what you have attempted so far, and what the result was.

Comment: @Dai There are other options if you believe that to be the case. Commenting is not the correct course of action - it may be more confusing to O.P., and doesn't conform to the best practices of StackOverflow.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson Yes, but consider that this question will inevitably be automatically deleted in 1-2 months' time due to it lacking value to other visitors - I don't invest my time in _matters-ephemeral_. I helped the OP by nudging them in the right direction - but the OP hasn't provided enough information for an actual answer, so would you rather I didn't help the OP at all? My complaint here is that SO _needs_ a way for us to post quick, low-effort, almost-answers without needing to resort to comment-replies - because I'm not going to write a full answer for a question like this.

Comment: It would be great if S.O. offered a Quick Answer feature, but it doesn't. I don't know that it will be deleted in any amount of time. It doesn't have enough information about what OP tried, and that's why I commented asking for that. If it had that, then it could be a good question, esp. with even more detail around the type of problem being solved. So that's what you should be asking for instead of leaving a code-only comment.

Answer (score 0):

Very, VERY rarely to you need to use a loop with any form of SQL database - it is set based.

You can use a sub-query in the where clause to filter e.g.

```
SELECT [date],col1, col2
FROM @demo 
WHERE col2 IN ( SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM @demo)
```

or you can use a self-join e.g.

```
SELECT t1.[date],t1.col1, t1.col2
FROM @demo t1
INNER JOIN @demo t2 ON t1.col2 = t2.col1
```

Comment: Thank you! The first method work. but the second one doesn't - Do you know maybe why?

Comment: I got exactly the same answer with both methods - did you type the ON clause correctly

Answer (score 0):

It would be more efficient to use `EXISTS` instead of `IN` as the `EXISTS` keyword evaluates `TRUE` or `FALSE`, but the `IN` keyword will compare all values in the corresponding subuery column. If you are using the `IN` operator, the SQL engine will scan all records fetched from the inner query. On the other hand, if we are using `EXISTS`, the SQL engine will stop the scanning process as soon as it found a match.

Query with `EXISTS` looks like

```
SELECT [date],col1, col2
FROM @demo d
WHERE EXISTS ( 
    SELECT 1 FROM @demo t
    WHERE t.col1 = d.col2
)
```